# Self study, non-linear optimization

Tags: optimization, reference-request, nonlinear-optimization

I want to self study a small (5 ECTS) introductory course on nonlinear optimization.

The course content on the university website is not very detailed, but I'll report it anyways:

> Modelling of practical problems as optimization problems, unconstrained optimization (optimality conditions, globally convergent descent methods, Newton method and Newton-type methods, globalization of locally convergent methods), elements of constrained optimization.

Lastly, the lectures are based on the book https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783034601429, which unfortunately is in German, so I can't really study on it.

Do you have any reference material/book I could learn to this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Begin with Boyd's Convex Analysis: [https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) (free).

And continue with Bertsekas' Nonlinear Programming: http://web.mit.edu/6.252/www/.